# stateless token expired

Tags: google-bigquery

I do upload several files every day and about half of them are successful. Some jobs return an error...

```
BigQuery error in load operation: Token invalid - Invalid token: Stateless token expired
```

I am using IST date format on my server (if that matters)

```
 date

Mon Jun 11 11:14:23 IST 2012
```

The relevant log of successful job is as follows:

```
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (1s) Current status: PENDING 
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (4s) Current status: PENDING 
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (7s) Current status: PENDING 
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (10s) Current status: PENDING 
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (14s) Current status: PENDING 
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (17s) Current status: RUNNING 
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (20s) Current status: RUNNING 
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (23s) Current status: RUNNING 
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (26s) Current status: RUNNING 
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (29s) Current status: RUNNING 
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (32s) Current status: RUNNING 
Waiting on job_9847e7bb715f40d994becff8e5f4ac1a ... (33s) Current status: DONE
```

Why do I get an error only for some of the files being uploaded?

Comment: Hi there, Please make sure that you are using the latest version of our Java API Client lib (if you are using Java).

Two things:

1. How are you handling your access and refresh token management? Are you requesting a new access token using your current refresh token?

2. Make sure that your server's clock is correct, and is synced with an NTP server.

Comment: I do not refresh token. I use the command ## /home/bigquery/bq load --max_bad_record=30000 -F '^'  company.junelog1 /data/2012061108.log.gz oneid:STRING,ativeid:STRING,ip:STRING,cbd:STRING,country:STRING... $$ If I try again, sometimes I am able to upload data successfully without getting token expired error.

Comment: When you get the error in the bq load operation, does the job actually succeed, or does the client just give an error? For example, if you do a `bq show -j <job_id_of_failure>`, does it show the job as succeeded or failed? My hunch is that the loop that runs to check the job state is failing, but the job may actually be completing successfully.

Comment: When I get this error, I do not get a job_id. The extract shown above is the log of successful jobs only. If I try the same command again, sometimes it loads the data successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another Googler pointed me to this potential issue - it's essentially a race condition in the Python Client Library (which the bq tool is based on). Google OAuth 2.0 access tokens currently are valid for 1 hour, after which the client lib (or bq) attempts to grab a new one using a stored refresh token. However, if you start a new data upload near the 1 hour boundary, the token will become invalid.

According to this thread, we are pushing out a new version of the underlying python lib very soon, and this should solve the issue in newer versions of the bq command line tool.

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/n3dZqmHMyp0